# Internally projective object gives a commuting square

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, pullback, epimorphisms

Let $\epsilon$ be a topos and $P$ be an object of $\mathcal{E}$ such that $(-)^P: \mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$ preserve epis then the right adjoint to pull back  $\Pi _P : \mathcal{E} /P \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$  priserves epis.
Show that for any $T$ in $\mathcal{E}$ and any epimorphism $X\rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{E}$ and any map $T×P\rightarrow Y$ there exists an epi $e:T'\rightarrow T$ and a commuting square
$\require{AMScd}$ \begin{CD} T'×P @>{}>> X\\ @VVV @VVV\\ T×P @>{}>> Y 
\end{CD}

I don't know if I can take $X×T$ as $T'$ and say $T'×P$ is the fibered product and since epis are stable under pull back the map $T'×P\rightarrow T×P$ is also epic and then since I have  $e×1 : T'×P \rightarrow T×P$ there is an epi $e:T'\rightarrow T$...

Comment: You haven't used the fact that $P$ is internally projective. A morphism $T \times P \to Y$ corresponds to a morphism $T \to Y^P$. You know $X^P \to Y^P$ is an epimorphism. Conclude.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know how to show the diagram commutes? Can you please help me with that too? I don't know hot does the map $T'×P\rightarrow Y$ works.....